# How to add specific js and css to a particular page in joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

I have added the html code using sp page builder extension also need to add css and js to this particular page in joomla 3. i am using t3 blank template is there any procedure to add this or any shortcut

```
<head>
  <title>Web Interactive</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

  <meta name="generator" content="xxxx 3.8.1">

  <!-- favicons -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="media/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="media/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="media/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="media/manifest.json">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="media/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">


  
  <script src="xx.js"></script>
  <script src="xxxx.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Interactive.css">
</head>
```

Comment: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22010/120

Comment: @mike please ask all Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Ok i will move this question to joomla stack exchange

Comment: This question has been cross-posted [here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/31626/12352).  @mike there is no benefit two creating to different accounts within the Stack Exchange Network.  I recommend that you merge your accounts.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20two%20accounts,that%20you%20own%20both%20accounts.